# how to get documents in Mac app using iPhone as scanner

Tags: swift, continuity

I am trying to add support for using iPhone's to scan documents into my app. When I right click in my text view I get the iPhone in the menu and I can select camera or document. When I select camera, the image is inserted into the textview automatically. When I select document, validrequestor is called and I return self for all types. The app works to there. When I select save the scan on the phone, the app crashes with;

> 2020-06-26 10:05:25.657246-0700 seeMyHealth[3825:106456] [General] An
> uncaught exception was raised
>
> 2020-06-26 10:05:25.657292-0700 seeMyHealth[3825:106456] [General]
> Target seeMyHealth.notesWindow returned by -[NSTextView
> validRequestorForSendType:returnType:] does not respond to selector
> readSelectionFromPasteboard:
>
> 2020-06-26 10:05:25.659379-0700 seeMyHealth[3825:106456] [General] (
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff376dfbe7
> __exceptionPreprocess + 250   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff709de5bf objc_exception_throw + 48

but I have both versions for readSelection defined in my app. What gives?

```
  override func validRequestor(forSendType sendType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType?, returnType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType?) -> Any?
  {
     return self
  }

  func readSelection(from pasteboard: NSPasteboard,type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }
  func readSelection(from pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

```
@objc func readSelectionFromPasteboard(_: NSPasteboard) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Maybe not many apps support this.